# Removing a text node with .remove() doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Fiddle at:** http://jsfiddle.net/6nN7G/

I'm using a shopify app for star reviews that outputs div.text - I want to remove the text that says X number of reviews: "19 reviews" and "3 reviews" in the HTML. On line 7 I do so with:

```
numberReviews.remove();
```

It appears to work in all of my browsers except for IE. Is there something else in the jQuery I'm using that IE doesn't like?

Comment: `remove()` is a jQuery function, but `numberReviews` is a DOM element.

Comment: Does `$(this).contents()[4]` actually point to the element you are after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`remove` function of nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove) is "an experimental API".

If you want to remove a node, Use the [`removeChild` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) :

```
numberReviews.parentNode.removeChild(numberReviews);
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I don't think I put in the Child part of removeChild when I just tried it.